# Node.js Piping the same readable stream into multiple (writable) targets

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, pipe, node.js-stream

I need to run two commands in series that need to read data from the same stream.
After piping a stream into another the buffer is emptied so i can't read data from that stream again so this doesn't work:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');

var inputStream = request('http://placehold.it/640x360');
var identify = spawn('identify',['-']);

inputStream.pipe(identify.stdin);

var chunks = [];
identify.stdout.on('data',function(chunk) {
  chunks.push(chunk);
});

identify.stdout.on('end',function() {
  var size = getSize(Buffer.concat(chunks)); //width
  var convert = spawn('convert',['-','-scale',size * 0.5,'png:-']);
  inputStream.pipe(convert.stdin);
  convert.stdout.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('half.png'));
});

function getSize(buffer){
  return parseInt(buffer.toString().split(' ')[2].split('x')[0]);
}
```

**Request** complains about this

```
Error: You cannot pipe after data has been emitted from the response.
```

and changing the **inputStream** to `fs.createWriteStream` yields the same issue of course.
I don't want to write into a file but *reuse* in some way the stream that **request** produces (or any other for that matter).

Is there a way to reuse a readable stream once it finishes piping?
What would be the best way to accomplish something like the above example?

Comment: Seems like you are using imagemick. You can pass value like 50% to -scale for scaling. You can also use https://npmjs.org/package/gm

Comment: @user568109 Yeah. That's not the issue here though. It's a more general question... it's imagemagick as it could be any other command/stream

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You have to create duplicate of the stream by piping it to two streams. You can create a simple stream with a PassThrough stream, it simply passes the input to the output.

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const PassThrough = require('stream').PassThrough;

const a = spawn('echo', ['hi user']);
const b = new PassThrough();
const c = new PassThrough();

a.stdout.pipe(b);
a.stdout.pipe(c);

let count = 0;
b.on('data', function (chunk) {
  count += chunk.length;
});
b.on('end', function () {
  console.log(count);
  c.pipe(process.stdout);
});
```

Output:

```
8
hi user
```

Comment: Used this technique with the Haraka mailserver attachment hooks to pipe the incoming stream into multiple mail account databases. This answer works.

Comment: Note that this technique only works if the spawned command outputs a number of bytes that does not fill the backpressure buffers. you can try and make it fail with a = spawn('head', ['-c', '200K', '/dev/urandom']);. If c is not piped out, at some point, a.stdout will pause piping out. b will drain and never end.

Comment: Is `a.stdout.pipe(c);` supposed to be `b.stdout.pipe(c);` ?

Comment: @DanielBeardsley No, it is copying streams. That would never work as you want to listen on b's data events.

Comment: I'm confused, you say that you can't process the same stream twice, but your solution is to.. process the same stream twice (with the PassThrough transform). This seems contradictory. Is this something special about the stdout streams?

Comment: I tested this and it certainly works. I think its not correct for you to say "you cannot process same [the] stream twice", since that's what you're doing. Your first statements about not being able to pipe a stream after its 'end' is the appropriate reason.

Comment: @BT If by stream you mean flow of data. In the answer's context stream refers to an object. Also the processing as asked in question concerns causal or sequential processing. Specifically OP wanted to calculate size of the stream and **then** use the stream from the beginning.

Comment: Tested this answer with images, and like @Jerome WAGNER said, it works if files are small enough. It did not work for me as request never ended and I got "socket hang up" errors.

Comment: I think this is no longer a valid statement: https://github.com/nodejs/readable-stream/blob/master/lib/_stream_readable.js#L508 readable streams can pipe data to multiple writeable streams.

Comment: @inf3rno The same was valid when I answered. The OP was using the stream incorrectly. He was piping after consuming the data.

Comment: @inf3rno You mean https://github.com/nodejs/readable-stream/blob/7bda7cc5c63fbd5cd63a3b08b424b3890771a7fb/lib/_stream_readable.js#L508 . :-)

Comment: Solution seems fine **but** watch out when operating on buffers - inplace buffer data modifications in b will be visible in c (if data chunk is string then no worry :) ).

Comment: Don't use this method because it creates issues if the streams are read at different rates.  Try this instead https://www.npmjs.com/package/readable-stream-clone worked well for me.

Comment: @kiwicomb123 nice, this happily worked out in my situation. Sadly I am not quite able to understand what the problem is, and you are not the first person to mention it. Are you able to elaborate? How is the stream reading rate measured? Is it about the actual time in seconds it takes to process stream data? The first stream is already finished by the time the final pipe starts reading, which is what confuses me. I guess I don't know something fundamental about how streams work. I've read the NodeJS Stream doc before but it's of little help. Do you know any other more useful resource?

Comment: @Avius I think its a race condition.  Under the assumption that you can't process the same stream twice, if one fork of the stream is finished processing the stream before the second one even starts then the second one will not work.  However, I don't have formal documentation to back this up,  I arrived at this conclusion by testing.

Comment: I can confirm that @kiwicomb123's suggestion also works in my situation. I've tried all kinds of things before (e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/cloneable-readable) to no avail. Here's my version of the class, updated to modern JS:
https://github.com/ditojs/dito/blob/master/packages/server/src/storage/CloneableReadable.js

Comment: For anybody doubting this, this is the suggested method of piping to two streams by the actual NodeJS team since 2011. https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/advanced/streams/how-to-use-stream-pipe/ They have a sample of streaming a process output to a file as well as `stdout`. `.pipe()` supports multiple entries. https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/236237829b26c1756104b5a37797a591e8a5aba6/lib/_stream_readable.js#L663 Also, `.pipe()` has backpressuring built-in for convenience. https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/backpressuring-in-streams/ If in doubt, never call `.write()` and only use `.pipe()`.

Comment: Piping to both a file and stdout may well be a special case since stdout is handled a bit different than other streams since it can't be closed.

Answer (score 12):

The first answer only works if streams take roughly the same amount of time to process data. If one takes significantly longer, the faster one will request new data, consequently overwriting the data still being used by the slower one (I had this problem after trying to solve it using a duplicate stream).

The following pattern worked very well for me. It uses a library based on Stream2 streams, Streamz, and Promises to synchronize async streams via a callback. Using the familiar example from the first answer:

```
spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
pass = require('stream').PassThrough;
streamz = require('streamz').PassThrough;
var Promise = require('bluebird');

a = spawn('echo', ['hi user']);
b = new pass;
c = new pass;   

a.stdout.pipe(streamz(combineStreamOperations)); 

function combineStreamOperations(data, next){
  Promise.join(b, c, function(b, c){ //perform n operations on the same data
  next(); //request more
}

count = 0;
b.on('data', function(chunk) { count += chunk.length; });
b.on('end', function() { console.log(count); c.pipe(process.stdout); });
```

Comment: Which part is actually overwriting the data? The code which overwrites should naturally throw an error.

Answer (score 6):

You can use this small npm package I created:

`readable-stream-clone`

With this you can reuse readable streams as many times as you need

Comment: does it suffer from the backpressure problem described [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19553837/node-js-piping-the-same-readable-stream-into-multiple-writable-targets#comment38541924_19561718)? What about producing an [empty file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19553837/node-js-piping-the-same-readable-stream-into-multiple-writable-targets#comment86192248_40874999) from the second pipe?  If you can elaborate a little that'd be awesome (to me and to your package reputation  :-)  ). Thanks in advance!

Comment: This lib does correct thing. It is so simple, that the entire source code can be copied here as an answer. This lib won't suffer from "backpressure problem" (see @maganap comment above). This lib will completely ignore backpressure mechanism.

Comment: There is also more smart alternative implementation: https://github.com/mcollina/cloneable-readable

Answer (score 5):

For general problem,  the following code works fine

```
var PassThrough = require('stream').PassThrough
a=PassThrough()
b1=PassThrough()
b2=PassThrough()
a.pipe(b1)
a.pipe(b2)
b1.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log('b1:', data.toString())
})
b2.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log('b2:', data.toString())
})
a.write('text')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have async operations on the PassThrough streams, the answers posted here won't work. 
A solution that works for async operations includes buffering the stream content and then creating streams from the buffered result.

1. To buffer the result you can use [concat-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concat-stream)

   ```
   const Promise = require('bluebird');
   const concat = require('concat-stream');
   const getBuffer = function(stream){
       return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
           var gotBuffer = function(buffer){
               resolve(buffer);
           }
           var concatStream = concat(gotBuffer);
           stream.on('error', reject);
           stream.pipe(concatStream);
       });
   }
   ```
2. To create streams from the buffer you can use:

   ```
   const { Readable } = require('stream');
   const getBufferStream = function(buffer){
       const stream = new Readable();
       stream.push(buffer);
       stream.push(null);
       return Promise.resolve(stream);
   }
   ```

Comment: I feel like this defeats the purpose of using streams, since you're loading the stream into memory, rather than handling it as it comes

Answer (score 1):

I have a different solution to write to two streams simultaneously, naturally, the time to write will be the addition of the two times, but I use it to respond to a download request, where I want to keep a copy of the downloaded file on my server (actually I use a S3 backup, so I cache the most used files locally to avoid multiple file transfers)

```
/**
 * A utility class made to write to a file while answering a file download request
 */
class TwoOutputStreams {
  constructor(streamOne, streamTwo) {
    this.streamOne = streamOne
    this.streamTwo = streamTwo
  }

  setHeader(header, value) {
    if (this.streamOne.setHeader)
      this.streamOne.setHeader(header, value)
    if (this.streamTwo.setHeader)
      this.streamTwo.setHeader(header, value)
  }

  write(chunk) {
    this.streamOne.write(chunk)
    this.streamTwo.write(chunk)
  }

  end() {
    this.streamOne.end()
    this.streamTwo.end()
  }
}
```

You can then use this as a regular OutputStream

```
const twoStreamsOut = new TwoOutputStreams(fileOut, responseStream)
```

and pass it to to your method as if it was a response or a fileOutputStream

Comment: writing to a stream without checking if return false (or buffer is full) would lead to a memory leak, consider how backpressure is implemented in nodejs. https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/backpressuring-in-streams

Answer (score -1):

What about piping into two or more streams not at the same time ?

For example :

```
var PassThrough = require('stream').PassThrough;
var mybiraryStream = stream.start(); //never ending audio stream
var file1 = fs.createWriteStream('file1.wav',{encoding:'binary'})
var file2 = fs.createWriteStream('file2.wav',{encoding:'binary'})
var mypass = PassThrough
mybinaryStream.pipe(mypass)
mypass.pipe(file1)
setTimeout(function(){
   mypass.pipe(file2);
},2000)
```

The above code does not produce any errors but the file2 is empty

Comment: in some way it helps me!

Comment: i think you've identified a problem, but it's confusing because this isn't an answer.