# How can you reuse a Readable stream in node.js?

Tags: node.js, stream

If I have an http server, and I want to write the same output to every request, it seems silly to recreate a new stream on every request. But, I'm noticing that if I pipe a file-stream somewhere for example, trying to pipe it again doesn't do anything.

How can I reuse a stream?

Comment: Ope, I think this answers my question actually: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19553837/node-js-piping-the-same-stream-into-multiple-writable-targets

Answer (score -3):

You can pipe it into a `Transform` stream do something with it and push the input to the transform back into the stream towards another transform.

Comment: Would you have an example of that perhaps?

Comment: An example would improve helpfulness of this answer drastically.