# Node Streams: piping a reference to a stream doesn't update the original stream

Tags: node.js, stream, pass-by-reference, node.js-stream

*Updated to better explain problem*: I'm trying to build a simple proxy server module which will allow implementers to listen for and modify the response which comes from the origin server. When the proxy receives the response, I am emitting a `customResponse` message with a reference to the response stream. Anybody listening to that event should be able to pipe onto the response and implement custom business logic. The module should take care of the **"final"** pipe back to the client - otherwise it wouldn't be a proxy (see example code below).

1. #### Installation

   ```
   npm install eventemitter3 && npm install event-stream && touch index.js
   ```
2. #### index.js

   ```
   var http = require("http");
   var EE3 = require('eventemitter3');
   var es = require("event-stream");

   var dispatcher = new EE3();
   dispatcher.on("customResponse", function (response) {
       // Implementers would implement duplex or transform streams here
       // and modify the stream data.
       response.pipe(es.mapSync(function (data) {
           return data.toString().replace("sometext", "othertext");
       }));
   });

   http.createServer(function (req, res) {
       // BEGIN MODULE CODE - THIS WILL HAVE AN API AND WILL RETURN
       // THE EVENT EMITTER FOR IMPLEMENTERS TO LISTEN TO
       http.request({
           host: "localhost",
           port: 9000,
           path: "/path/to/a/file.txt"
       }, function (response) {
           // Dispatch the event, allow consumers to pipe onto response
           dispatcher.emit("customResponse", response);

           // Here's where the problem is - the "response" stream
           // may have been piped onto, but we don't have a reference
           // to that new stream. If the data was modified by a consumer,
           // we don't see that new data here.
           response.pipe(res);
       }).end();
       // END MODULE CODE
   }).listen(7000);
   ```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Node.js Piping the same stream into multiple (writable) targets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19553837/node-js-piping-the-same-stream-into-multiple-writable-targets)

Comment: I updated the question to more clearly explain.  I understand pipe chaining and other things addressed by that answer. My situation is different. I am trying to "expose" a stream to the outside world, allow consumers to pipe onto it, and then perform the final *crucial* pipe internally.  How can I do this?