# Cannot pipe after data has been emitted from the response nodejs

Tags: node.js, pipe

I've been experiencing a problem with the `require` library of node js. When I try to pipe to a file and a stream on response, I get the error: `you cannot pipe after data has been emitted from the response`. This is because I do some calculations before really piping the data.

Example:

```
var request = require('request')
var fs = require('fs')
var through2 = require('through2')

options = {
    url: 'url-to-fetch-a-file'
};

var req = request(options)
req.on('response',function(res){
    //Some computations to remove files potentially
    //These computations take quite somme time.
    //Function that creates path recursively
    createPath(path,function(){
        var file = fs.createWriteStream(path+fname)
        var stream = through2.obj(function (chunk, enc, callback) {
            this.push(chunk)
            callback()
        })

        req.pipe(file)
        req.pipe(stream)
    })
})
```

If I just pipe to the stream without any calculations, it's just fine. How can I pipe to both a file and stream using `request` module in nodejs?

I found this:[Node.js Piping the same readable stream into multiple (writable) targets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19553837/node-js-piping-the-same-stream-into-multiple-writable-targets) but it is not the same thing. There, piping happens 2 times in a different tick. This example pipes like the answer in the question and still receives an error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19553837/node-js-piping-the-same-stream-into-multiple-writable-targets/19561718#19561718

Comment: This is not the same though?

Comment: In streams, you cannot reuse the piped data. Are you looking for pub-sub architecture ?

Comment: Can you tell what is happening in the calculation, does it involve reading from the req stream. If it does not I will reopen the question.

Comment: The request is to fetch a file. The location to write the file has a limited size and the size of the file is known beforehand. The computations delete the oldest files in the directory where the file will be written untill the file fits in the location.

Comment: Alright. Here you go. But please add code as you do get incorrect output when you run with it.

Comment: I wanted to answer my own question to help people with this problem. I had quite some issues with it. What do you mean? Do I need to correct it so it has valid output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of piping directly to the file you can add a listener to the `stream` you defined. So you can replace `req.pipe(file)` with

```
stream.on('data',function(data){
    file.write(data)
})

stream.on('end',function(){
    file.end()
})
```

or

```
stream.pipe(file)
```

This will pause the stream untill its read, something that doesn't happen with the `request` module.

More info: https://github.com/request/request/issues/887

Comment: So you meant to pass response to stream then to file in the question ? Then why not do `stream.pipe(file)`. What you wrote is equivalent of that.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I'll edit. But I still think this is a usefull question...