# Do I need to create duplex stream to write to and then read from through piping

Tags: javascript, node.js

Suppose I have the following code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var stream1 = fs.createReadStream('file1.txt');
var stream2 = fs.createWriteStream('file2.txt');
var stream3 = fs.createWriteStream('file3.txt');
```

This statement `stream1.pipe(stream2);` returns `stream2`, which is writable, not readable. But what if I then wanted to pipe it again, like so:

```
stream1.pipe(stream2).pipe(stream3);
```

Would I need to create `stream2` as `duplex`? And if so, how?

Comment: You can simply do `stream1.pipe(stream2)` and `stream1.pipe(stream3)` just don't use chaining.

Comment: @Molda, thanks, but what if I wanted to use chaining?

Comment: Can you explain what you are actualy trying to achieve and why do you need chaining? Also see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/19561718/3284355 it might help.

Comment: I was just trying to understand when I need to use `duplex` streams. It's for learning purposes only.