# request: how to pipe file and keep the response object

Tags: node.js, stream, request, fs

I use npm request. I want to download and write a file to the filesystem and after that-use the returned response object for further processing.

I know that I can pipe the response object directly but afterwards I have no response object more for further processing

```
var result = await request(builtReq).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(myFilePath));
```

So my implementation at the moment looks like this:

```
var result = await request(builtReq);
```

But I am not able to pipe the result object because the streamable state is false.

So I need a way to keep the return of the request and to write the file to the filesystem. Can I reset the stream state or somehow keep the response obj and write the file at the same time?
I tried to implement the write file manually via. fs.writeFile() after I received the response obj but I had problems with file encodings because I can receive anything and I ended up with broken files.

Has somebody an idea how to solve that?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want the *response* object (this contains the status code and headers), or do you need the response body in-memory?

If you only want the response object, and still want the body written to a file, you can grab the response like so:

```
var response;

await request(builtReq).on('response', r => {
    console.log('Response received: ' + r);
    response = r;
}).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(myFilePath));

console.log('Finished saving file, response is still ' + response);
```

If you need to process the actual body, you have a couple options:

- Keep your existing code as-is, then just read the file off the disk right after it finishes (since you are using `await`, that would be the next line) and process it in memory.
- Pipe the input stream to multiple places -- one to the file write stream, and the other to an in-memory buffer (using a standard `on('data')` handler). Once the stream finishes, the file is saved and you can process the in-memory buffer. See related question [node.js piping the same readable stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19553837/node-js-piping-the-same-readable-stream-into-multiple-writable-targets) for several different examples.

Comment: This is exactly what I need just a little problem.
I return the response object from that sendRequest function and the await strangely doesn't wait for the response to be received.

So I end up with an undefined return.
I dont quite understand how he can resolve the await and pipe the image before the response event is triggered.
Is where another event that I can use that comes before that? Is where some documentation with a list of events?
I am almost where this is exactly what I need.

Comment: Ah, I failed to include that in my answer - you are using "await" (which would require request to return a promise) but this is not a promise-based library. The `await` keyword doesn't mean anything here. You need to do the basic async approach, of adding an event handler for when the pipe finishes.  In your case, though, I'd recommend https://github.com/request/request-promise instead - this wraps the library with promises for you.  If you are going to process the response in memory anyway, just abandon the streaming, use a promise, and then save to disk afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

remember promises can only be resolved once.

so to solve your problem:

```js
var promise = request(builtReq)

// now do what ever number of operations you need
result.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(myFilePath));

promise.then(r=>console.log('i will still get data here :)');
promise.then(r=>console.log('and here !');
promise.then(r=>console.log('and here !!');

var result = await promise; // and here to !!
```

a promise once resolve, the `.then` will always get the result.