# How to get content encoding of a readstream without consuming its data in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, chunks, chunked-encoding, node-streams

I have a **`readStream`** and I want to know its content encoding.

One of the way which I know is through [detect-character-encoding](https://www.npmjs.com/package/detect-character-encoding) module. But it requires me to read the **chunks(Buffers)** from **readStream** due to which I lose the data, as I require **readStream** further in the code logic as well.

So is there a way to know the **readStream's** encoding without leading to data(chunk) losses.

Comment: You've asked that question already here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69025247/how-to-read-data-of-a-nodejs-stream-without-it-being-lost
If the provided answer does not help you, please add a comment/edit the original question instead of posting the same question again.

Comment: The question posted earlier had the problem of data loss which according to the question was solved. Here I am facing another problem that instead of reading the stream is there a way to know its encoding.