The stream in Node.js returning empty
const command = new GetObjectCommand(getObjectParams);                                                                                                                                                                              
const data = await s3Client.send(command);                                                                                                                                                                                          
const stream = data.Body;     
const [streamForRecordCount, streamForEntireRecords] = duplicateStream(stream);                                                                                                                                                     
const recordedCount = await processRecordCount(streamForRecordCount);                                                                                                                                                               
const records = await processEntireRecords(streamForEntireRecords);     
console.log("records", records);

Above is code in Node.js where a stream of a CSV file is fetched from AWS S3.  A stream is split into two since streams are consumable and cannot be used by both. This code works perfectly fine and returns recordedCount and records as expected. The details of the methods are as follows:
async function processRecordCount(stream) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let firstLineProcessed = false;
    const results = [];

    const parser = csvParser();

    stream.on('error', (err) => {
      console.error('Error with the input stream:', err);
      reject(err);
    });

    parser.on('error', (err) => {
      console.error('Error parsing CSV:', err);
      reject(err);
    });

    parser.on('end', () => {
      if (results.length === 0) {
        reject(new Error('CSV is empty'));
      } else {
        resolve(results[0]); 
      }
    });

    stream.pipe(parser);

    parser.on('data', (row) => {
      if (!firstLineProcessed) {
        results.push(row);
        firstLineProcessed = true;

        stream.unpipe(parser);
        parser.end(); 
      }
    });
  });
}

async function processEntireRecords(stream) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const records = [];
    const parser = csvParser({
      trim: true,
      skip_empty_lines: true,
      columns: true,
      skipLines: 1 // first line is not a header
    });

    stream.on('error', (err) => {
      console.error('Error with the input stream:', err);
      reject(err);
    });

    parser.on('error', (err) => {
      console.error('Error parsing CSV:', err);
      reject(err);
    });

    parser.on('data', (record) => {
        const filteredRecord = Object.fromEntries(
          Object.entries(record)
            .filter(([, value]) => value !== '')
            .map(([key, value]) => [key, { S: value }])
        );
        records.push(filteredRecord);
    });

    parser.on('end', () => {
      console.log('Stream processing completed.');
      resolve(records);
    });

    stream.pipe(parser);
  });
}

function duplicateStream(originalStream) {
  let stream1 = new PassThrough();
  let stream2 = new PassThrough();
  originalStream.pipe(stream1);
  originalStream.pipe(stream2);
  return [stream1, stream2];
}

Th problem is when an additional method is added that uses the returned value from the aforementioned method as a parameter, console.log("records", records) becomes empty. The items is records.
async function batchWriteItems(items, tableName) {
  const batchSize = 25;
  const limit = pLimit(1);
  const batches = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i += batchSize) {
    batches.push(items.slice(i, i + batchSize));
  }

  const promises = batches.map(batch => limit(async () => {
    const params = {
      RequestItems: {
        [tableName]: batch.map(item => ({
          PutRequest: {
            Item: item
          }
        }))
      }
    };

    try {
      const command = new BatchWriteItemCommand(params);
      await dynamoDocClient.send(command);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error sending batch write command:", error);
      throw error;
    }
  }));

  await Promise.all(promises);
}

Removing processRecordCount and only using the two methods works:
const stream = data.Body;                                                                                                                                                                    
const records = await processEntireRecords(stream); 
await batchWriteItems(records, tableName); 


In general, if a function is declared async, you don't need an explicit return new Promise(), since it automatically wraps the return value in a promise.

Could it be the source the issue where the returned value records is unpredictably empty ?

No. Wrapping a promise in another promise is usually innocuous.

@Barmar More fitting here: "if a function already explicitly returns a new Promise, you don't need to declare it as async"

"A stream is split into two since streams are consumable and cannot be used by both" - I'm pretty sure your problem is with that. Though it's unclear what batchWriteItems has to do with this

@Bergi I thought that might be the problem, but they seem to be using the same code as https://stackoverflow.com/a/59280825/1491895

@Bergi Could you elaborate?

Looking at it again, I think the problem is that you don't start consuming the second stream until the first method finished. That might drop data, depending on timing of events.

@Bergi using await Promise.all to call the two methods simultaneously still made no difference.
