# Reusing a Generator in Multiple Functions/Methods

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, iterator, generator

I am trying to create a file reader object (from readFileSync) and serve the lines from a generator function. My intention is to pass this gnerator object to multiple functions and sequentialy parse a file. However, after using the generator in a single function, the state of the generator shift from suspended to closed. I come from a Python background and this is a very much possible operation in Python. Would like to know what I am doing wrong here. Following is the code I used:

Generator function definition (I am using readFileSync and it is not async, please disregard that for the time being as I am trying to get the generator working):

```
function* getFileGen(path: string){
  const fileContent = fs
  .readFileSync(path, {
    encoding: "utf-8",
    flag: "r",
  })
  .split("\n");

  while(true){
      const thisLine = fileContent.shift();
      if(!thisLine){
        break;
      }
      yield thisLine; 
  }
}
```

The two functions in which I would like to use the generator in:

```
function getFirstFew(stream: Generator){
  let i = 0;
  for(let v of stream){
    console.log(v);
    if(i > 1){
      break;
    }
    i++;
  }
}

function getNextFew(stream: Generator){
  let i = 0;
  for(let v of stream){
    console.log(v);
    if(i > 7){
      break;
    }
    i++;
  }
```

And finally create a generator and pass it sequentially to two functions that would print a number of lines:

```
const myStream = getFileGen('path/to/file');

getFirstFew(myStream);
getNextFew(myStream);
```

The first function executes correctly and prints 3 lines; however by the time the generator is passed to the getNextFew function, it has already closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of):

> In for...of loops, abrupt iteration termination can be caused by break, throw or return. In these cases, **the iterator is closed**.

And, specifically:

> **Do not reuse generators**
>
> **Generators should not be re-used, even if the for...of loop is terminated early, for example via the break keyword**. Upon exiting a loop, the generator is closed and trying to iterate over it again does not yield any further results.

Emphasis mine.

I'll admit though, I'm not very strong with JS, so I can't recommend a comparable workaround. You may need to use a list or another strict structure that you have more control over.

You may be able to implement a `tee` function comparable to Python's `tee` that creates a copy of the iterator, then iterate one of the copies.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, before I looked at your answer I suspected, for of should be the problem and used something like, while(line = this.stream.next().value){ ... //line} which worked without terminating the the generator.

Comment: @c00der Using that idea, you could create a `take_n` function that pulls `n` objects from an iterator and returns them. If I were in your place, I'd just whip up some helpers. That actually sounds like chill afternoon mini-project.

Comment: That would be a cool idea. Will give it a shot. Actually, in the version of it I am implementing, only a few rows of the file is handled by one function and the rest of it by another.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great application for Node's streams API.

You can [use a generator as a source for a Node.js ReadableStream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#streamreadablefromiterable-options), then [duplicate it using PassThrough](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#class-streampassthrough).

A bit like this answer here: [Node.js Piping the same readable stream into multiple (writable) targets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19553837/node-js-piping-the-same-readable-stream-into-multiple-writable-targets)

Basically you can do this:

```js
const { PassThrough, Readable } = require("stream");

function* getFileGen(path: string) {
  const fileContent = fs
  .readFileSync(path, {
    encoding: "utf-8",
    flag: "r",
  })
  .split("\n");

  while(true) {
      const thisLine = fileContent.shift();
      if(!thisLine) {
        break;
      }
      yield thisLine; 
  }
}

// Set up per: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#streamreadablefromiterable-options
const fileReadlineStream = Readable.from(getFileGen(), { objectMode: false });

const firstFew = new PassThrough();
const nextFew = new PassThrough();

fileReadlineStream.pipe(firstFew);
fileReadlineStream.pipe(nextFew);

firstFew.on("data", (d) => {
    console.log("First few received:", d);
});

nextFew.on("data", (d) => {
    console.log("Next few received:", d);
});
```

If you want to transform that file in some way you will be best off using a TransformStream. In execution you might want to prioritise one stream's processing over another; I'm not an expert on the exact behaviour but generally you can [handle that with buffering](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#buffering).

Answer (score 0):

A `for of` loop always closes the iterator by calling `.return()` on it in the end (if the method exists). You can prevent that by removing (overwriting) the method

```
const myStream = getFileGen('path/to/file');
myStream.return = undefined;
getFirstFew(myStream);
getNextFew(myStream);
```

but that's crude. I'd rather do something like

```
function keptOpen(iterable) {
    const iterator = iterable[Symbol.iterator]()
    return {
        [Symbol.iterator]() { return this; },
        next(v) { return iterator.next(); },
    };
}
```

and use it like

```
const myStream = keptOpen(getFileGen('path/to/file'));
getFirstFew(myStream);
getNextFew(myStream);
```

However, notice that this will work only with generator functions that don't care about being kept open. If they expect that their `.return()` method is called so that they can dispose their allocated resources, `keptOpen` will make them leak.