# Use Read Stream from AWS S3 getObject to read and upload to a different bucket

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, nodejs-stream

I am trying to read a file from a third party AWS S3 bucket which is in a `.gz` format. I need to process the data in the file and upload the file to our own S3 Bucket.

For reading the file, I am creating a readStream from S3.getBucket as shown below:

```
const fileStream = externalS3.getObject({Bucket: <bucket-name>, Key: <key>}).createReadStream();
```

For making the code more efficient, I am planning to use the same `fileStream` for both processing the contents and uploading to our own S3. I have the code below, which does not  upload the file to the internal S3 bucket.

```
import Stream from "stream";

const uploadStream = fileStream.pipe(new stream.PassThrough());
const readStream = fileStream.pipe(new stream.PassThrough());

await internalS3.upload({Bucket:<bucket-name>, Key: <key>, Body: uploadStream})
.on("httpUploadProgress", progress => {console.log(progress)})
.on("error", error => {console.log(error)})
.promise();

readStream.pipe(createGunzip())
.on("error", err =>{console.log(err)})
.pipe(JSONStream.parse())
.on("data", data => {console.log(data)});
```

However, the code below successfully uploads the file to the internal s3 bucket.

```
const uploadStream = fileStream.pipe(new stream.PassThrough());


await internalS3.upload({Bucket:<bucket-name>, Key: <key>, Body: uploadStream})
.on("httpUploadProgress", progress => {console.log(progress)})
.on("error", error => {console.log(error)})
.promise();
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

NOTE: If I use separate `fileStream`s to upload and read data, it works fine. However, I need to achieve this using the same fileStream.

Comment: Your script works fine for me. Could you please show the error when the object is not getting uploaded to S3? Also please mention the node version you're using.

Comment: @Rahul Sharma - First of all Thanks for responding. I do not get an error. Seems like the upload to S3 is just stuck. Node version I am using is 16.6.2

Comment: What is the file size you're trying to upload? Could you also tell the time it takes to process the stream **(1)** uploading the file to s3 **(2)** reading and creating gunzip and logging it to console?

Comment: The file size varies, but is mostly up of 1GB. The upload, if I use individual streams, usually take about 2 minutes. gunzip is a lot quicker. I am performing more async functions on the unzipped data that I have not mentioned here. With those functions, it will take longer.

Comment: I think this is happening because the stream has already ended while sdk was trying to upload the file because the `readStream` is a lot quicker and requesting data at higher rate than the upload which has to put data on a remote location over a network. See related issue: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/3004. You can fix this by the solution mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33879208/1973735.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files that you are trying to upload to S3 have a relatively large size (~1 GB) as mentioned by OP. Two streams are being created here piping the single `fileStream`:

```
const uploadStream = fileStream.pipe(new stream.PassThrough());
const readStream = fileStream.pipe(new stream.PassThrough());
```

While the operations on `readStream` are less time consuming `uploadStream` is responsible for uploading the file to a remote location, in this case S3, over a network which takes relatively more time. This also means that the `readStream` is pulling/requesting the data from the `fileStream` at a higher rate. By the time `readStream` has finished, the `fileStream` is already consumed and the `.upload` call to `aws sdk` hangs. See this [issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/3004).

You can fix it by making use of this [library](https://github.com/ZJONSSON/streamz) to synchronise the two different streams. An example of how to achieve that can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33879208/1973735).